# Cannot convert parameter from 'int' to 'int&'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm following the pluralsight C++ course, and in it is the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
T max(T& t1, T& t2)
{
    return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Max of 33 and 44 is " << max(33, 44) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I typed over this piece of code, but unlike the code of the course, I get an error message:

```
C2664: 'max' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'int &'
```

The code in the course is written in Visual Studio Express 2010, while mine is written in Visual Studio Ultimate 2010.

---

EDIT

Thanks to everybody (even Kate Gregory herself) for providing answers and clearing everything up.

Comment: Do you have a link to the course, and is that the _exact_ code from the course?

Comment: The course is called Pluralsight C++ fundamentals, the first part. It is the exact code. There is also code that uses max with strings and a user defined class, but it doesn't have anything to do with the integers being passed into  max, just showing the functionality of max.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because literals (and rvalues in general) cannot be passed by non-const reference (since it would make no sense if the callee could change them). Either pass by value or by const reference:

```
template <class T>
T max(const T& t1, const T& t2)
{
    return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}
```

or

```
template <class T>
T max(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both 33 and 44 are rvalues; they're passed to the function by value and not by reference. The compiler can't convert these two to the expected type `int &`. Use variables (lvalues) as they can be passed by reference:

```
int a = 33, b = 44;

max(a, b); // 44
```

Since you're merely dealing with fundamental types here (`int`), passing by reference is redundant. Passing by value causes a copy, but the difference will be negligible:

```
template <class T>
T max(T t1, T t2);
```

Here we can pass both rvalues and lvalues. But there *is* the chance that you could pass in a object of class type. In that case passing by reference is recommended.

But for the case where we don't want a copy and want both lvalues and rvalues, we can pass by `const` reference:

```
template <class T>
T max(T const &t1, T const &t2);
```

In C++11 you can pass the arguments by a *universal-reference* so that we can bind glvalues:

```
template <class T>
T max(T&& t1, T&& t2);

int main()
{
    int a{0}, b{0};

    max(a, b);
    max(1, 2);
}
```

If you want to keep the lvalue-reference syntax in your original code, you can use this lvalue shim:

```
template<typename T>
T& lvalue(T&& t)
{
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    max(lvalue(1), lvalue(2));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer here turns out to lie in the unrelated code you didn't use in your test. Absolutely my little max() should take either by value, or const-ref, and that was just a brain-slip that I will fix as soon as I can.

But the full demo code works beautifully. That's because it includes more headers, one of which brings in xutility and therefore `std::max`. This led me to not notice that my `max` wasn't being used. I'll redo the demo with a name like `biggest` to eliminate that happening again. And in the meantime, yes, if you want to pass literals to a function by reference, they need to be const ref. I knew that, but didn't think of it while writing the test harness, and then was fooled when bad code appeared to work. I should have re-read the code more carefully: thanks for calling this to my attention. (And thanks for taking the course and I hope you're finding it helpful.)

Comment: :-) Thanks a lot for your response! And yes, I find the course helpful. I've been using C# for some years, and always wanted to try C++ but was... fearful? The course just let me slip in easily.

Comment: The problem of accidentally calling `std::max` instead of your own `max` is only possible with a `using namespace std;` somewhere in your own code. [We know this is a very bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/). Shame on you! ;)

Comment: :-) it is a bad idea in a header file - this goes to show it can bite you in a .cpp file too.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass temporary value as `T&`. Since you don't change arguments, use `const T&` instead

BTW, there is built-in `max` function

Comment: Yes, they say in the course that there is a max. It is a simple demo showing how to use a template.

Answer (score 3):

Integer literals cannot be passed as non-const reference. Besides, your `max` function can work with `const` references, so mark them appropriately:

```
T max(const T& t1, const T& t2)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you defined your function with parameters by reference, you cannot use anything but variable names for said parameters - and you try to use numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Small remark. You can use your initial code of function "**max**". Try change call from `max(34, 44)` to `max<const int>(34,44)`. Sometime it can be useful.

```c++
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
T max(T& t1, T& t2)
{
   return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Max of 33 and 44 is " << max<const int>(33, 44) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haven't come across that one yet. Thanks.